# Submitting to ArXiv while awaiting ACM journal peer review: any concerns?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, copyright, arxiv, acm

In the situation where I've **submitted** my article to an **ACM journal**, **awaiting peer-review**, and considering publishing it on **ArXiv** (https://arxiv.org), could this pose any issues?

ACM, Author Guidelines, it is mentioned:

> "ACM authors may post all versions of their work, with the exception
> of the final published "Version of Record", to non-commercial
> repositories such as ArXiv."

https://dl.acm.org/journal/dlt/author-guidelines

However, it is not entirely clear to me whether this statement also answers my question.

Any insights, excluding suggestions to consult ACM editors?

Answer (score 13):

The statement is clear enough. Yes you can post a version prior to the final published one. This would include the version under review.

Note that with some exceptions, both CS and math are pretty free about permitting pre-prints. Be aware that there are exceptions, however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ACM allows it.

Does the specific journal allow it? In theory it would put you in conflict with the anonymization policy of many ACM venues.

For some communities within ACM arXiv is still new, and they are still figuring out how it fits into their publishing workflows.

I'd pose this question directly to the journal you're submitting to.